# File is 'locked' when I try to save but is not locked in finder or get info

Tags: macos, terminal

I was fixing something and tried to save it, but it said "The document could not be saved. The file is locked. " but when I checked in finder, the file was not locked.

I dont think its an issue with the contents, but here they are anyway:

```
#!/bin/sh


SCRIPT_DIR=$(pwd)
cd SCRIPT_DIR
Python3 .test1.py
```

Comment: How is that related to python?

Comment: I am using it to run a python program.

Comment: good point though. i removed the python tag.

Comment: What editor?  If the file is in use, the app might not be able to open it in "write" mode.

Comment: textedit. I try to save my edits (it was working in a previous edit in which I just added the "." to the start of ".test1.py".

Comment: I am here searching for an answer because I am having the same problem with a TextEdit file. In my case, the file has sat open, with edits, unsaved for over a day and when I went to save it, the system reports that it is locked, offers me the option to save anyway, which does not work, and suggests that I change permissions. Similarly to the OP, Finder Get Info shows no permission problems -- UNLESS somehow TE forgot in the meantime that I am indeed in the same account that opened the file. That seems unlikely, but it's a weird error. I've seen it before and only been able to save by renaming.

Comment: Well I only edited it over 2 minutes, and the error was there, so probably not.